# regarding OOP in php

Tags: php, oop

I am in the process of re educating myself in the programming of OOP
in PHP.

I have been under the erroneous assumption that all variables not static inside a class def
had to be proceeded with $this->. I finally stumbled over myself with a variable naming collision
and am now relearning, somewhat, the way of php OOP.

My present question is:

Can you mark a method property set with $this-> as public, private, or protected?

I have done;

```
 class _DEMO
      {
         private $this->someVar = 'whatever';

      }
```

and I get a syntax error.
then:

```
class _DEMO
      {
       public function __construct($_ip)
              {
               $this->ip = $_ip; // <<< how can I set access on this property?
              }
      }
```

As of now I don't know how to use properties with access levels set
other than to declare static properties.

OK, so I tried
     class _DEMO
           {
             public $_someVar = 'so and so';
           }
     $_a = new _DEMO()
     print $_a->someVar // NADA

So, I take it that the variable can be declared this way but not initialized?

on second thought, OOPs! I saw the problem with variable reference $_testy and $this->testy, should be $this->_testy

```
class _DEMO
  {
   private static $_doTell = 'Well??...';
   private $_testy = "So What? ";
   public function __construct($_ip)
          {
           $this->_testy .= " right Now?";
           $this->ip = $_ip;
           $this->soWhat = 'Boo!...';
          }

   public function getVar($_var, $_addon)
          {
           $this->setVar($_var, $_addon);
           switch($_var)
              {
               case 'soWhat':
               return $this->soWhat;
               break;
               case 'ip':
               return $this->ip;
               break;
               case 'doTell':
               return self::$_doTell;
               break;
               default:
               break;
              }
           }

   private function setVar($_var, $_input)
           {
            switch($_var)
              {
               case 'soWhat':
               $this->soWhat .= $_input;
               break;
               case 'ip':
               $this->ip .= $_input;
               break;
               case 'doTell':
               self::$_doTell .= $_input;
               break;
               default:
               break;
              }
           }
  }
$_test = new _DEMO('Hello??...');
print "Test result 1: ".$_test->ip;
print "<br>Test result 2: ".$_test->getVar('doTell', ' So, how old are you??');
print "<br>Test result 3: \$_test::\$_doTell; Fatal error: Cannot access private property _DEMO::$_doTell";
print "<br>Test result 4: ".$_test->testy; // <<<< prints " right Now?" without errors about trying to 
//access private members
```

Comment: [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and [Visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: YOu need to learn the PHP syntax rules. If you had, you'd know why your first code snippet would never work.

Comment: Don't use `$this->` while declaring, it's already implied (`class foo {private $someVar;}`

Answer (score 1):

Properties are declared at the start of the class like:

```
public $property1;
private $property2;
protected $property3;
```

Then,

#### 1. all properties can be accessed from any method of the same class like `$this->property`.

#### 2. `$property1` can be accessed from all methods in ANY class.

#### 3. `$property2` can be accessed from all methods in the SAME class.

#### 4. `$property3` can be accessed from all methods in the SAME class and classes which EXTEND THE SAME class.

E.g. You can access a private property from a public method:

```
class A {
    private $property;

    public function getProperty() {
       return $this->property
    }
```

Then, in a controller, you could do:

```
$obj = new A;
$property = $obj->getProperty();
```

but not:

```
$obj = new A;
$property = $obj->property;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can:

```
class MySampleClass {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $aStringVariable;


    /**
     * @param string $anIP
     */
    protected function __construct( $anIP ) {

        $this->aStringVariable = $anIP;

    }

}


// How to use the class

$myClassObject = new MySampleClass( '192.168.0.1' );
```

You might wish to download the eval-version of [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), a PHP IDE. The IDE might help, since it points out errors while you type and PHPStorm provides auto-completion.

Additionally, have a look in the [PHP Wiki of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info). The [Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) provides valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of using property.

```
class HelloProperty{
    private $mySimpleProperty;

    public function setSimpleProperty($mySimpleProperty){
        $this->mySimpleProperty = $mySimpleProperty;
    }


    public function getSimpleProperty(){
        return $this->mySimpleProperty;
    }

}


$obj = new HelloProperty();
$obj->setSimpleProperty('Hello Property');
echo $obj->getSimpleProperty();
```

:)